# Why does bringing a helium filled latex balloon close to my ear make it feel pressurized?

Tags: pressure, acoustics, everyday-life, biology

Title pretty much says it all.

Got my son some balloons for his 1st birthday. He was playing with them while I was holding him and everytime he brought one closed to my ear it made my ear feel pressurized. Similar to taking off in an airplane, but less intense.

What's the mechanism that's causing this? Is static electricity in the balloon causing fluid in the inner ear to shift or something?

Comment: I've felt an odd sensation before too (as I hold a balloon several cm from my ear), but I always attributed it to a deadening of sound. As if the balloon absorbed the sounds and prevented them from penetrating the balloon creating a dead sound sensation. Does this describe your sensation?

Comment: I'm sure it's the same sensation, but I don't know that it's sound deadening. I don't get the same sensation if hold a pillow or other sound deadening object close to my ear.

Comment: Could it be electrostatics?

Comment: Hypothesis: a pressurised balloon does the same thing to sound, that a pressurised eardrum does. Not deadening exactly, but a particular distortion that only comes from a taut membrane with a pressure difference across it. The result would be a different frequency response to other sound deadening objects, plus some internal reflections and resonances.
You hear the sound and your brain thinks your ear is mismatched in pressure.